# remove css class from specific part using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a div whose id is `divId` and I have written a JS script through which I am highlighting the "this" keyword.
Here is the JS code

```
            var regex = new RegExp('this',"gi");
     document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML=document.getElementById("divId").
    innerHTML.replace(regex, function(matched) 
{return '<span class=\'highlight\'>' + matched + '</span>';})
```

and here is the div

```
This is the text This is the text This is the text This is the text 
This is the text This is the text This is the text This is the text 
This is the text This is the text This is the text This is the text
```

Now I want to create a button on which I click and `highlight` class has been removed.I have tried this `document.getElementById("divId").className = ""` but it didn't work.As I am new to JS so now after my efforts now I am passing this problem to SO experts.How can I remove the class from all `this` word inside a div
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On [newer browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) (IE8+ and such) you can do this:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#divId span.highlight");
var index;
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    list[index].className = "";
}
```

On older browsers, you could do this:

```
var list = document.getElementById("divId").getElementsByTagName("span");
var index;
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    if (list[index].className === "highlight") {
        list[index].className = "";
    }
}
```

In both cases, I'm assuming "highlight" is the only class on these spans.

Comment: I am using firefox 10.0.2 .. and this solution is also not working

Comment: @Despicable: Both solutions work just fine: http://jsbin.com/owafoh/1 ([source](http://jsbin.com/owafoh/1/edit)), http://jsbin.com/owafoh/2 ([source](http://jsbin.com/owafoh/2/edit)).

Answer (score 1):

If you use or are willing to include jquery on your page, you can do this:

```
$('#divId span').removeClass('highlight');
```

Nice thing is that other classes are not removed.

There are similar functions in other js-frameworks, such as prototype.js

Comment: Why is my suggestion 'not useful'?  It's the easiest way, and it does what is needed.  The other answers remove all classes on the element.

Comment: Because I need the solution in pure Javascript ot in jquery any way i will vote you up :)

Comment: Thanks for the recognition! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var div = document.getElementById("divId");
var divs = div.getElementsByTagName('span')
for (var i=0; i<divs.length;i++){
divs[i].className  = '';
}
```

**Or**

```
document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = function() {
var regex = new RegExp('<span class="highlight">this</span>','gi');
var div = document.getElementById("divId");
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace(regex,"this");
```

Comment: That does nothing. If you assigned it back to `div.innerHTML`, it would at least replace the *first* one, but not subsequent ones.

Comment: `divs[i].setAttribute('class','');` won't work correctly on several versions of IE. Use the reflected `className` property.